# threejs hdr environment map in editor

Tags: three.js, editor, hdr

I want to expand the threejs editor to be able to load hdr environment maps similar to this example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_envmaps_hdr

I loaded the example code succesfully in app.js Start() function, somehow when the exact same code is executed in the editor, the example torus appears bright white without any shading.

Is there anything that is automatically done when an environment map is loaded? Or why is it not working properly?

This is the code i am using:

```
            //renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
            //renderer.setClearColor( new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ) );
            standardMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
                map: null,
                bumpScale: - 0.05,
                color: 0xffffff,
                metalness: 0.0,
                roughness: 1.0,
                shading: THREE.SmoothShading
            } );

            var genCubeUrls = function( prefix, postfix ) {
                return [
                    prefix + 'px' + postfix, prefix + 'nx' + postfix,
                    prefix + 'py' + postfix, prefix + 'ny' + postfix,
                    prefix + 'pz' + postfix, prefix + 'nz' + postfix
                ];
            };
            var hdrUrls = genCubeUrls( "./textures/cube/pisaHDR/", ".hdr" );
            new THREE.HDRCubeTextureLoader().load( THREE.UnsignedByteType, hdrUrls, function ( hdrCubeMap ) {

                var pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( hdrCubeMap );
                pmremGenerator.update( renderer );

                var pmremCubeUVPacker = new THREE.PMREMCubeUVPacker( pmremGenerator.cubeLods );
                pmremCubeUVPacker.update( renderer );

                hdrCubeRenderTarget = pmremCubeUVPacker.CubeUVRenderTarget;
                standardMaterial.envMap = hdrCubeRenderTarget.texture;
                standardMaterial.needsUpdate = true;
                SetChildEnvMaps(editor.scene,hdrCubeRenderTarget.texture);

            } );
            //renderer.gammaInput = true;
            //renderer.gammaOutput = true;
            var geometry = new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry( 18, 8, 150, 20 );;
            var torusMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, standardMaterial );
            torusMesh1.position.x = 0.0;
            torusMesh1.castShadow = true;
            torusMesh1.receiveShadow = true;
            editor.scene.add( torusMesh1 );
            var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            textureLoader.load( "./textures/roughness_map.jpg", function( map ) {
                map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                map.anisotropy = 4;
                map.repeat.set( 9, 2 );
                standardMaterial.roughnessMap = map;
                standardMaterial.bumpMap = map;
                standardMaterial.needsUpdate = true;
            } );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is work at last threejs revision 83-dev. I can add Mash from tutorial to the Editor's scene by click. http://image.prntscr.com/image/5adb87108f3045a69333916fc2f24d61.png
With revision 82 got the same result as you.